# Python RDS Update Script Not Actually Updating

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pymysql

I've built my code base primarily in PHP and am seeing what I can put together in Python. One key challenge I've wanted to tackle is to be able to read and write to my MySQL database through AWS RDS. I played around with a script using pymysql and thought I had solved my problems. I run a short update script:

```
usql1 = "UPDATE table_name SET STATE='Georgia', SCORE2='1' WHERE ID=1"
response1 = cursor.execute(usql1)
```

When I print the results in my Python code I see the state changed to Georgia and the `SCORE2` field changed to `1`. However when I refresh the table in MySQL Workbench nothing has changed.

Why would the results be changing when I retrieve and print the table in my Python script but not in the underlying database? Does this have something to do with how cursors are initiated with pymysql?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try committing the change after cursor executed the query with `connection.commit()`

Comment: That did the trick. I didn't know that you had to run a separate line to commit. Thanks Arpit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute your update, MySQL is implicitly starting a transaction. You need to commit this transaction by calling `connection.commit()` after you execute your update to keep the transaction from automatically rolling back when you disconnect.